# Swagger 3 generates Properties with missing type if type is missing in OpenApi-Specification

Tags: c#, swagger, openapi

I try to generate c# code out of an openApi specification  which is missing the *type* element on some properties with swagger 3.

The properties with missing *type* are generated in code also without *type*, which is an compiler error.

As far as I understand *type* is not mandatory in openApi spec, but shouldn't be there some fallback to csharps `object` or `string` to keep the code compiling?

Is there any swagger option to force this behavior or has anyone some other idea how to solve this?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

To answer it myself, I now use NSwag (I have to run OpenApi Generator before I can perform Nswag)  with *Visual Studio 2019*  [REST API Client Code Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ChristianResmaHelle.APIClientCodeGenerator).

Output is more leightweight, as it generates all code into one file. The types like body-types are in my case not always properly named (rather body0, body1,...) which is no problem, as I have to convert into my own interface anyway.